# Change the paths to user folders(Shell Folders) with Powershell

Tags: powershell, special-folders, known-folders

How to change the paths to user folders (Shell Folders) with Powershell?
Required:

1. get the path to the folder
   $mydoc = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('MyDocuments')
   C:\Users\shay\Documents
2. Change the drive letters in a variable $mydoc - C:\Users\shay\Documents to d:\Users\shay\Documents ??
3. Create a folder - d:\Users\shay\Documents ??
4. Copy the folder C:\Users\shay\Documents to d:\Users\shay\Documents ??
5. Set the path to the My Documents system folder - d:\Users\shay\Documents ??
   I am grateful in advance for your help.

Comment: The main part of your question (redefining the locations of known shell folders) is addressed in the linked duplicate. To change the drive letter, use `$mynewdoc = $mydoc -replace '^c', 'd'`. To create a folder, use [`New-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/new-item). To copy a folder, use [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item)

Comment: how set the path to the My Documents system folder - d:\Users\shay\Documents ??

Comment: Try the function in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25709702/45375) to the linked duplicate.