# Change Documents default location with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am trying to change the default location of the documents folder using powershell or cmd specifically.

What I have tried:
I have tried changing both the shell folders and user folders registry path and restarted the computer but nothing happens:

```
reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /f /v Personal /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "C:\users\JatonJustice\desktop\testfolder"
```

But I still see it in the users folder in documents(even after restarting. The picture below is after restarting the computer.):
[image]

I tried using the answer from here: [Set location of Special Folders with PowerShell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25709398/set-location-of-special-folders-with-powershell)

However that didn't seem to do anything either:
[image]

If anyone has any ideas for this, that would be awesome. If I have to I guess I can use wswshell but that is the last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found out that `reg add "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders" /f /v Personal /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d "C:\users\JatonJustice\desktop\testfolder"` works but when you are using an `azure` domain account or an `amazon workspace` account, the registry location for the `user shell folders` will be in a different place

you can verify the user location of the shell folder key by navigating to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER` and double checking which account you are in. There are accounts like `.DEFAULT`, or `S-1-5-18` (SYSTEM ACCOUNT), etc.

Comment: Do you mean when using the Azure AD?