# How do I Set-Up Powershell to open a specific script at startup?

Tags: powershell

I would like to configure PowerShell to run the default profile.ps1 script from a local folder, instead of my configured Documents folder.

I initially configured my Document Folder to be saved inside my OnDrive to prevent losing my Documents in case of a crash.  However, due to that change, when I launch Powershell, it is trying to execute the profile.ps1 script from the preconfigured OneDrive/Documents.profile.ps1 and that is not allowed for security reasons.

I would like to configure Powershell to run the profile.ps1 from a local folder on my C: instead.  How do I proceed?

I Opened PowerShell and ran the $PROFILE command.  It displayed the OneDrive Documents folder location.

```
C:\Users\Joey\OneDrive\Documents\WindowsPowerShell\profile.ps1
```

I think I can point the $PROFILE variable to the local C: folder, but can't seem to find its location to update it.  I Tried adding a PROFILE variable to the System Environment Variable, but that did not work.

Please advise.

Comment: A guide to the answers: The question asks about _selectively_ changing the location that `$PROFILE` points to: This _isn't supported_ (as of this writing, but it's unlikely to change). You can _indirectly_ change what `$PROFILE` points to, by _fundamentally changing the location of the well-known Documents folder_, which, of course, is a much more fundamental change.

Answer (score 1):

You can find a detailed explanation here (in fact multiple) - https://serverfault.com/questions/195397/change-the-powershell-profile-directory - but the short version is, you can adjust that by editing the `Personal` key within the registry here :

`Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders`

So it no longer points to `%USERPROFILES%\Documents`, and instead points somewhere that works for your purposes.

Comment: Thank you for your link reference.  I use the Powershell command to Edit the Registry to point it to my local C: folder and it works just fine when I call Command as well as when I Open a new Terminal in Visual Studio Code.:  New-ItemProperty 
  'HKCU:\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\User Shell Folders' 
  Personal -Value 'Your New Path Here' -Type ExpandString -Force

Comment: It's worth noting that this only _indirectly_ changes the `$PROFILE` location, namely by changing the location of the user's Documents folder, i.e. changes the location of _all documents_. The registry approach is [discouraged](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20031103-00/?p=41973) and _not officially supported_, but still seems to work in practice. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25709702/45375) shows an (untested by me) solution that uses the _supported_ approach via P/Invoking the `SHSetKnownFolderPath` WinAPI function.

Answer (score 1):

Note: If changing your *entire Documents folder* back to a local-only location is an option (away from OneDrive), see [Keith Langmead's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76424845/45375).

---

**The value(s) of the [automatic `$PROFILE` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#profile) can *not* be changed**, and given that dot-sourcing a different file from the profile file in the fixed location is *not* an option in your case, you'll have to **use the PowerShell [CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_powershell_exe) with its `-File` parameter to emulate profile loading**<sup>[1]</sup>

```bash
powershell.exe -NoExit -File C:\path\to\your\local\profile.ps1
```

<sup>Note: If you add `-NoProfile` before `-File`, then *none* of the - potentially multiple - [profile files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Profiles) will be loaded. If there are no other profiles, you can use `-NoProfile`; otherwise, just delete / don't create one in the location that `$PROFILE` points to.</sup>

You can create a shortcut file (`*.lnk`) or a batch file (`*.cmd`) to facilitate launching your PowerShell sessions with this command line.

---

<sup>[1] `-File` implicitly [dot-sources](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-) the specified script file, i.e. executes it *directly in the global scope*, which is also how profiles are loaded.</sup>